# Looking for a mouse with a couple extra buttons for programming to copy/paste

Tags: mouse

I've been browsing dozens of mice today--Microsoft, Logitech, Razer, Steelseries, etc.  I'm looking for an idiot-proof Linux/Ubuntu/Fedora mouse that has **extra buttons**:

1. left mouse click, right mouse click, scroll wheel, scroll wheel (*standard stuff*)
2. side buttons for thumb forward & back (*usually on mice today*)
3. **two additional buttons that I can map to copy and paste**

So essentially, a standard mouse, plus **2 or 3 additional buttons**.  I'd like to program them for custom commands such as ctrl+c and ctrl+v, to help with code editing.

Al the mice like this seem to have issues in Linux.  I'd love to simply find one that is easy to setup.  Any advice?

Comment: When programming, you want to use the keyboard at all times. Not constantly moving your hand between keyboard and mouse when copy pasting. So i think your idea less efficient then you imagine.

Comment: I understand your feelings here.  Most people would agree with you.  I do use vim/nano of course, but lately I use web editors like Cloud9 and Codenvy, and having a mouse is key.

Answer (score 1):

Do you look for a trackball ?

Here is something of Logitech which works with Ubuntu.

http://nxadm.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/logitech-wireless-trackball-m570-on-ubuntu/

Is this what you look for ?

Logitech announced weeks ago, that they support Linux.

Comment: Interesting.  So, easystroke allows me to use quick mouse movements into shortcuts, instead of needing extra buttons.  I hadn't thought of that idea.  I need to think about that, it could be all that I need.  Thanks.